# Can digital signature certificate be used for code signing?

Tags: code-signing, digital-signature

I am an individual developer and want to use code signing for my exes. I am new to this and don't know much about it. Can a normal digital signature certificate be used for code signing? Verisign, thawte etc are costly for me. [This site looks affrodable for me](http://www.emudhradigital.com/). They sell digital signatures. Will it serve my purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code signing certificate must have proper flag set in ExtKeyUsage extension, i.e. this is a special kind  of certificate. This company doesn't seem to offer such certificates.